# Eclipse result integer value only

Tags: java

Here is my code, Eclipse always return integer value of results, even if h is double. Please help me to fix this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double h=0.0;

    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
        h=h+ 1/i;           
    }
    System.out.println("Harmonic sum "+h);
    System.out.println("Harmonic sum "+String.format("%.4f", h));
```

Result:

```
Harmonic sum 1.0
Harmonic sum 1,0000
```

Comment: You're doing int division! Divide with doubles

Comment: And this has **nothing** to do with Eclipse

Comment: Integer math. When you divide an `int` by an `int`, the result is an `int`. You cast one (or both) of the operands to a `double` and it will work as expected. `h += 1/(double)i;`

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast the result of your division into **double**

**Try this out:**

```
h=h+ (double)1/i;
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Why are you answering an obvious duplicate question?

Comment: And if you must do so, please make sure that the quality of your answer surpasses most of the duplicate answers to be found.

Comment: Casting the result wouldn't help, but the code you wrote doesn't do what you say anyway. It actually casts one _operand_, the `1`, to `double`, and then JLS 5.6.2 promotes the other operand `i` to `double` and the division is done in `double` which works -- but was more accurately and quickly stated by ElliotFrisch.